# How to resize View with pull the edge gesture?

Tags: android

I am looking for solution as on images bellow:

[image]

I need to have two resizable views in one layout.
User just needs to move separation line to the top (ScrolView B becames higher) or to the bottom (ScrolView A becames higher).

What is the best solution, which gives this behavior? I know that I can extends from ScrollView and override `public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` and  `protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)`, but may be there is more simple solution. I want to avoid calculation the math of moving. Thank you for any information.

Comment: So you basically want the split screen view from Android N. Why not just base your code off that? http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/stackdivider/DividerView.java you should be able to throw away everything that has to do with stacks and actually running activities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to solve this problem quickly, I suggest you use [Split Pane Layout](https://github.com/MobiDevelop/android-split-pane-layout).

**Usage :**

```
 <com.mobidevelop.spl.widget.SplitPaneLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:spl="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/splitPaneLayout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        spl:splitterSize="12dp"
        spl:orientation="vertical"
        spl:splitterPosition="50%"
        spl:splitterBackground="#781b23">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="" />

        </ScrollView>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text=""/>

        </ScrollView>

 </com.mobidevelop.spl.widget.SplitPaneLayout>
```

I solved your problem by creating two xmls for portrait and landscape mode. For portrait mode, i set the panel's orientation as vertical by adding `spl:orientation="vertical"` and for lanscape mode, i set the panel's orientation as horizontal by adding `spl:orientation="horizontal"`.

After doing all this, I got the look like below.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Made this into an answer.

You basically want the split screen view from Android N. You could base your code off the open source implementation in SystemUI:
http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/stackdivider/DividerView.java

Along with this for the handle:
http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/stackdivider/DividerHandleView.java

You can throw away all code that has to do with stacks (which is the row of screenshots off different activities in your history), buss events and anything that has to do with running another activity, such as the code for Vsyncing between apps (mSurfaceFlingerOffsetMs).

It should leave you with quite small and easy to use classes.